# Erro em exercício Javascript - true == false

Tags: javascript

Olá, podem me ajudar com este erro? Estou fazendo um curso introdutório de Javascript em uma plataforma de ensino online, e estou com um problema em um exercício que pede:

> Primeiro de tudo precisamos saber que um banco está fechado quando é
>   fim de semana (sábado ou domingo) e não está no horário bancário (9 às
>   15hs).
>
> Defina a função possoIrAoBanco que, receba dois parâmetros, o primeiro
>   é diaDaSemana (string) e o segundo horaAtual(numero), a função deve
>   retornar true, apenas se o banco estiver aberto.
>
> Lembre-se que você pode fazer o que é necessário usando o return sem fazer uso de if/else.

Essa plataforma acaba tendo algumas exigências que mesmo eu sendo bem inciante posso ver que são um pouco desnecessárias. Meu código está assim:

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
  var domingo = "domingo";
  var segunda = "segunda-feira";
  var terca = "terça-feira";
  var quarta = "quarta-feira";
  var quinta = "quinta-feira";
  var sexta = "sexta-feira";
  var sabado = "sábado";
  return diaDaSemana != sabado || diaDaSemana != domingo && diaDaSemana == segunda || diaDaSemana == terca || diaDaSemana == quarta || diaDaSemana == quinta || diaDaSemana == sexta && horaAtual < 15 && horaAtual > 9;
}
```

O erro que aparece é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: Sim, essa plataforma desensina em vez de ensinar, já percebemos isto.

Comment: Infelizmente... Mas você pode me ajudar com este erro?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no `return`, como você está trabalhando com várias condições em uma expressão maior com os operadores && ou ||, o correto é escrever cada uma das duas condições entre parênteses. No seu caso ficaria:

```
(diaDaSemana != sabado || diaDaSemana != domingo) && (diaDaSemana == segunda || diaDaSemana == terca || diaDaSemana == quarta || diaDaSemana == quinta || diaDaSemana == sexta) && (horaAtual < 15 && horaAtual > 9);
```

Além disso, você pode diminuir ela só para:

```
(diaDaSemana != sabado || diaDaSemana != domingo) && (horaAtual > 9 && horaAtual < 15);
```

Comment: Eu havia tentado da forma menor e o site não aceitou. Mas com os parênteses foi certinho! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Entendi. Que nada a ver o site. Boa sorte nos estudos.

Answer (score 0):

```
function possoIrAoBanco ( diaDaSemana,horaAtual) {
    var naoPode = ('Sábado');
    var naoAbre = ('Domingo');
    return diaDaSemana!= naoPode && diaDaSemana!= naoAbre && horaAtual >=9 
&& horaAtual<=15;
```

/  / #Desta forma também pode funcionar, é importante que as strings estejam separadas, se for exercicios da plataforma DH é bom ter muita atenção aos detalhes do enunciado pois são feitos para que você tenha problemas e pense sobre eles.